# Adding a scroll viewer for data row in Datagrid is visible

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am having a datagrid in which i have to display a log text message with scroll bar for each row of the grid

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding LogDetails}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"                                             ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Log " Binding="{Binding Path=LogDetail}" Width="4*" MinWidth="550">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
                        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="300"/>
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
<DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=ScriptDatasetInfo}" />
                        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="60000" />
                        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="300"/>
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
```

But the Scroll bar is not visible on selcting the Datarow

Comment: Can you post your LogDetails collection with its data int it???

Comment: that is an observable collection..